# Validating only one attribute using ActiveRecord::Base#valid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, rails-activerecord

I'm looking for a way to use `ActiveRecord::Base#valid?` on only one attribute. Consider the following example, inspired by [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#format):

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company

  validates :legacy_code, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/ }
  validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :company }
end
```

Calling `Product#valid?` will trigger a SQL query because of the `name` validation:

```
Product.new(legacy_code: "helloworld", company: c).valid?
  Product Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products"  WHERE ("products"."name" IS NULL AND "products"."company_id" = 1) LIMIT 1
=> true
```

Now, I'm only looking to validate the `legacy_code` attribute:

```
Product.new(legacy_code: "helloworld").valid?
  Product Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "products"  WHERE ("products"."name" IS NULL AND "products"."company_id" IS NULL) LIMIT 1
=> true
```

See the issue? I'd love to use something like `Product#valid?(:legacy_code)` and avoid the query that's trying to validate an attribute I don't care about.

So far, my solution is to use a `Product#valid_legacy_code?` method that I can call independently, and call this method as well in the validation declarations on my model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up writing a gem for that: https://github.com/KevinBongart/valid_attribute

```
# Test only one attribute:
product.valid_attribute?(:company)      # => true
product.valid_attribute?(:name)         # => true
product.valid_attribute?(:legacy_code)  # => false

# Test several attributes at once, like a boss:
product.valid_attribute?(:company, :name)               # => true
product.valid_attribute?(:company, :name, :legacy_code) # => false

# Wow, you can even filter down to a specific validator:
product.valid_attribute?(name: :format)                     # => true
product.valid_attribute?(name: [:format, :uniqueness])      # => true
product.valid_attribute?(name: :format, company: :presence) # => true
```